# C# NEST ElastichSearch property store but not index

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I want the B field stored in Elasticsearch but never indexing. When I search for `"Nash"` I do not want to search within the B field. So the B field is not indexed in elastic.

```
    [ElasticsearchType(Name = "ES6")]
    public class ES6
    {
        public string A { get; set; }

        public string B { get; set; }
    }

    elasticClient.IndexDocument(new ES6 { A = "John", B = "Nash" });

    elasticClient.IndexDocument(new ES6 { A = "Nash", B = "John" });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a field not be indexed you can use the NEST `Attributes` to show that the field should not be indexed.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/attribute-mapping.html

In your example, it would probably be something like this:

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "ES6")]
public class ES6
{
    [Text]
    public string A { get; set; }

    [Keyword(Index = false)]
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

Setting it to `keyword` will make sure it is not analyzed and setting `Index = false` will tell Elastic not to index it.